# Tkinter button command argument

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have been looking into tkinter with python as I am seriously interested in GUi's and thought it would be a great place to start. I went through a good few tutorials like The New Boston set and one or two theres to grab hold of the basics. Now I am trying to pass an 'argument' through a botton so that my program will move on to my IF statement and I am having no joy.

Please find attached code:

```
  try:
    from tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from Tkinter import *
eod = 'no'
selection = []
selection1 = 'nothing'
while eod != 'yes':

    def beer():
        selection.append('Beer')
        selection1 = 'Beer'
    def wine():
        selection.append('Wine')
    def whiskey():
        selection.append('Whiskey')

    welcomeGUI = Tk()
    welcomeGUI.geometry('400x200+100+200')
    welcomeGUI.title('Drinks Despenser')

    welcomLabel1 = Label(welcomeGUI, text='Drinks-O-Matic', font='Times 22 bold').grid(row=0,column=2)
    welcomLabel2 = Label(welcomeGUI, text='Please select drink', font='Times 16 bold').grid(row=1,column=2)


    beerButton = Button(welcomeGUI, text='Beer', font='Times 16 bold',command=beer()).grid(row=6,column=1)
    wineButton = Button(welcomeGUI, text='Wine', font='Times 16 bold').grid(row=6,column=2)
    whiskeyButton = Button(welcomeGUI, text='Whiskey', font='Times 16 bold').grid(row=6,column=3)

    if selection1 is 'Beer':
        welcomeGUI.destroy()
        beerGUI = Tk()
        beerGUI.geometry('400x200+100+200')
        beerGUI.title('Beer Despenser')

        beerGUI.mainloop()


    welcomeGUI.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok there is a lot going on here so I have a couple of things that I think will help you.

You need to move your `def` out of the while loop for all the functions. They should be defined only once in the beginning of the file.

Also, you are assigning variables to the `Button` object after you call the `grid` method. That method returns `None` so you shouldn't do that because you are assigning variables `None` instead of the actual button object as you intend to. You should assign the variables the button object alone and then call `varname.grid()` later.

Finally, to address your question: when you write `command=beer()` you are once again calling the function beer and assigning its *return value*  to the command parameter. When you are using Tkinter you must assign only the function name to the command parameter such as `command=beer`. However, if you have to pass it arguments you can use `lambda`. For example: `command=lambda: beer(arg1, arg2)`.

P.S.
When comparing strings you should say

```
if selection1 == "Beer":
```

not

```
if selection1 is "Beer":
```

`is` tests for identity not equality and you want to test equality.

EDIT: You also should unindent the `try` at the top of your file.

Also because selection1 is a local variable in the function `beer` it won't work, you need to declare it a global

```
def beer():
    global selection1
    selection.append('Beer')
    selection1 = 'Beer'
```

Furthermore, you need to destroy the window or the if statement in the while loop won't run.

```
def beer(window):
    global selection1
    selection.append('Beer')
    selection1 = 'Beer'
    window.destroy()
```

and then you need to pass the `welcomeGUI` Tk instance to the function like so

```
beerButton = Button(welcomeGUI, text='Beer', font='Times 16 bold',command=lambda: beer(welcomeGUI)).grid(row=6,column=1)
```

One last thing. I would remove the while loop all together and have a button on the beer window to call back the main welcome window because putting two mainloops in the while loop is not going to be a good thing.

Comment: Thanks a million for the input.